# how to convert varchar string db date into date/timstamp

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need a time comparison.

I have a database field with a `varchar` field that contains column name `date`.

I have fetched two dates on the bases of `id.like` in code.

Now i want to convert these strings into actual date/time so I can compare them.

I am trying this:

```
    $sql="SELECT date From tbl_info where  id=12 "; //first date string
    $sql2="SELECT date From tbl_info where id=14 "; //2nd date string
    $result= mysql_query($sql) or die(msyql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
      {
     $date=$row["date"]. "<br>";       
     echo  $date ;
      }
     $result2= mysql_query($sql2) or die(msyql_error());
      while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
       {
       $date2=$row2["date"]. "<br>";
        echo  $date2;
        }
       $value=strtotime('H,i',$date);
      echo "<br/>Value= :".$value ;

      $value2=strtotime('H,i',$date2);
      echo "<br/>Value2= :".$value2;
```

**RESULTS:**

Value= :-48386

Value2= :-48386

What is the actual way to do it right, because `strtotime` does not work.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Why would you store a date in a varchar when MySQL has much more suited [date and datetime types?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html)

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
date('H,i', strtotime($date)); //$date will be the date you want to use

$value2=date('H,i', strtotime($date2));
```

Comment: Thanks @sgt. but it now gives "18:00" what is this? it shd'nt like this

Comment: which format do you want?? `H` means `00 to 23`.. you will get all the formats - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php . just take a look.

Comment: thanks for giving nice link for formats.but i am unable to understand why it is giving ":00" ? can you elaborate

Comment: what is in the variable you are passing?

Comment: into variables while inserting i am using $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');